# How to give for each image a different link in a For

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

so I made a for to get all the images, but I also want that each image has a own link (when you click on it). how do I do that?

```
<div class="container">

    <h2>Champions</h2>
    <hr>    

    <?php $champions = array("Ahri", "Akali", "Alistar", "Amumu", "Anivia", "Annie", "Ashe", "Blitzcrank", "Brand", "Caitlyn", "Cassiopeia", "Chogath", "Corki", "DrMundo", "Evelynn", "Ezreal", "FiddleSticks", "Fiora", "Fizz", "Galio", "Gangplank", "Garen", "Gragas", "Graves", "Hecarim", "Heimerdinger", "Irelia", "Janna", "JarvanIV", "Jax", "Karma", "Karthus", "Kassadin", "Katarina", "Kayle", "Kennen", "KogMaw", "Leblanc", "LeeSin", "Leona", "Lulu", "Lux", "Malphite", "Malzahar", "Maokai", "MasterYi", "MissFortune", "Mordekaiser", "Morgana", "Nasus", "Nautilus", "Nidalee", "Nocturne", "Nunu", "Olaf", "Orianna", "Pantheon", "Poppy", "Rammus", "Renekton", "Riven", "Rumble", "Ryze", "Sejuani", "Shaco", "Shen", "Shyvana", "Singed", "Sion", "Sivir", "Skarner", "Sona", "Soraka", "Swain", "Talon", "Taric", "Teemo", "Tristana", "Trundle", "Tryndamere", "TwistedFate", "Twitch", "Udyr", "Urgot", "Varus", "Vayne", "Veigar", "Viktor", "Vladimir", "Volibear", "Warwick", "MonkeyKing", "Xerath", "XinZhao", "Yorick", "Ziggs", "Zilean");?>
    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($champions); $i++)

            <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">

            <img class="img" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/champion/<?php echo $champions[$i]?>.png">  

            </span>
    @endfor
```

Comment: You mean when you click on an image it should point to somewhere?

Comment: @HyderB. yes a href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">

    <h2>Champions</h2>
    <hr>    

    <?php $champions = array("Ahri", "Akali", "Alistar", "Amumu", "Anivia", "Annie", "Ashe", "Blitzcrank", "Brand", "Caitlyn", "Cassiopeia", "Chogath", "Corki", "DrMundo", "Evelynn", "Ezreal", "FiddleSticks", "Fiora", "Fizz", "Galio", "Gangplank", "Garen", "Gragas", "Graves", "Hecarim", "Heimerdinger", "Irelia", "Janna", "JarvanIV", "Jax", "Karma", "Karthus", "Kassadin", "Katarina", "Kayle", "Kennen", "KogMaw", "Leblanc", "LeeSin", "Leona", "Lulu", "Lux", "Malphite", "Malzahar", "Maokai", "MasterYi", "MissFortune", "Mordekaiser", "Morgana", "Nasus", "Nautilus", "Nidalee", "Nocturne", "Nunu", "Olaf", "Orianna", "Pantheon", "Poppy", "Rammus", "Renekton", "Riven", "Rumble", "Ryze", "Sejuani", "Shaco", "Shen", "Shyvana", "Singed", "Sion", "Sivir", "Skarner", "Sona", "Soraka", "Swain", "Talon", "Taric", "Teemo", "Tristana", "Trundle", "Tryndamere", "TwistedFate", "Twitch", "Udyr", "Urgot", "Varus", "Vayne", "Veigar", "Viktor", "Vladimir", "Volibear", "Warwick", "MonkeyKing", "Xerath", "XinZhao", "Yorick", "Ziggs", "Zilean");?>
    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($champions); $i++)

            <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">

            <a href="http://gameinfo.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/<?php echo strtolower($champions[$i]); ?>" target="_new"><img class="img" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/champion/<?php echo $champions[$i]?>.png"></a>

            </span>
    @endfor
```

For different link just edit `href="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/champion/<?php echo $champions[$i]; ?>.png"`

For example I want to open Yahoo:`href="http://yahoo.com"`

If you don't like have new window (new tab) just remove `target="_new"`

Comment: thanks but i need 135 different links for each image.. how does that work?

Comment: For example you need `http://gameinfo.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/zed/` then `href="http://gameinfo.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/<?php echo $champions[$i]; ?>"`

Comment: I edited my answer you need to use this URL:`http://gameinfo.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/<?php echo strtolower($champions[$i]); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can link the image to link as follows:

simply wrap it up in "a" tag

```
<a href="PUT_YOUR_CUSTOM_LINK_HERE">
<img class="img" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/champion/<?php echo $champions[$i]?>.png">
</a> <!-- close link tag-->
```

Comment: you can iterate the links ... just like image links

Answer (score 0):

To add a link to your image, you simply wrap it:

```
      <?php $champions = array("Ahri", "Akali", "Alistar", "Amumu", "Anivia", "Annie", "Ashe", "Blitzcrank", "Brand", "Caitlyn", "Cassiopeia", "Chogath", "Corki", "DrMundo", "Evelynn", "Ezreal", "FiddleSticks", "Fiora", "Fizz", "Galio", "Gangplank", "Garen", "Gragas", "Graves", "Hecarim", "Heimerdinger", "Irelia", "Janna", "JarvanIV", "Jax", "Karma", "Karthus", "Kassadin", "Katarina", "Kayle", "Kennen", "KogMaw", "Leblanc", "LeeSin", "Leona", "Lulu", "Lux", "Malphite", "Malzahar", "Maokai", "MasterYi", "MissFortune", "Mordekaiser", "Morgana", "Nasus", "Nautilus", "Nidalee", "Nocturne", "Nunu", "Olaf", "Orianna", "Pantheon", "Poppy", "Rammus", "Renekton", "Riven", "Rumble", "Ryze", "Sejuani", "Shaco", "Shen", "Shyvana", "Singed", "Sion", "Sivir", "Skarner", "Sona", "Soraka", "Swain", "Talon", "Taric", "Teemo", "Tristana", "Trundle", "Tryndamere", "TwistedFate", "Twitch", "Udyr", "Urgot", "Varus", "Vayne", "Veigar", "Viktor", "Vladimir", "Volibear", "Warwick", "MonkeyKing", "Xerath", "XinZhao", "Yorick", "Ziggs", "Zilean");?>
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($champions); $i++)

                    <span class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">

 <a href="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/champion/<?php echo $champions[$i]?>.png">
     <img class="img" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/champion/<?php echo $champions[$i]?>.png">  

    </a>
                    </span>
            @endfor
```

Comment: it works but how can i do it with a different link for the href

Comment: What link should it be?

Comment: the last word of the link has to change for each image